# How to return byte array from alchemy C

Tags: apache-flex, alchemy

I have written a alchemy code for reading the byte array that i have passed from flex.

When i print the value i get the error

cannot convert "OggS" to flash.utils.ByteArray

Alchemy Code

```
static AS3_Val readFile(void* self, AS3_Val args)
{

    unsigned int e_length;  
    AS3_Val e_data = AS3_Undefined();   
    AS3_ArrayValue( args, "IntType, AS3ValType", &e_length, &e_data );  
    //unsigned char * data = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char)  * (e_length +  1));
    char *buffer;
    buffer = (char *)malloc(e_length+ 3);
    AS3_ByteArray_seek(e_data, 0, SEEK_SET);
    AS3_ByteArray_readBytes(buffer, e_data, e_length);
    free(buffer);
    return AS3_String(buffer);

}
```

Flex Code:

```
private function copyByteArray(content:String):void{

    try{

    byteData = new ByteArray();
        //byteData.writeUTFBytes(contents);
        var dec:Base64Decoder = new Base64Decoder();
        dec.decode(content);
        byteData = dec.toByteArray();
        Alert.show("byte Array   " + byteData.length +" ::  " +contents.length);

        var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("Files/test.spx");
        stream = new FileStream();
        stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);

    var byteArr:ByteArray;
        var loader:CLibInit = new CLibInit();
        var lib:Object = loader.init();

        var byteStr:String;

    byteArr = lib.readFile( byteData.length, byteData);

    stream.writeBytes(byteArr);
        stream.close();

    }
    catch (ex: ErrorEvent){
        Alert.show("error");

    }
}
```

Comment: In the alchemy code, why are you freeing the buffer before returning it? And why create an AS3_String from it when you want to return a ByteArray?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that your Alchemy code returns a String, but your Flex code is trying to assign it to a ByteArray.  Here's the AS3 equivalent of what you're doing:

```
var ba:ByteArray= new String();     // bad
```

If you want to return a ByteArray from Alchemy you need to create it in and fill it with data.

Passing ByteArrays like this is probably inefficient.  See this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4891641/how-to-pass-bytearray-to-c-code-in-alchemy) (and the links the answers point to) on how to pass data directly via Alchemy's RAM.

Comment: You'll have to get a lot more specific as to what you tried (perhaps in another SO question).  I have a project that's passing ByteArray data via Alchemy's RAM and it works fine.

Comment: I can't, but the links in the SO question I linked to have lots of example code that works.