# How to pass ByteArray to C code in alchemy?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, alchemy

I want to pass a byte array object from flex code to C code.How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Passing a ByteArray from Flex to C++
http://nexus.zteo.com/blog/2008/12/22/adobe-alchemy-passing-a-bytearray-from-flex-to-c/

Answer (score 1):

Multiple approaches outlined here:
http://blog.debit.nl/2009/03/using-bytearrays-in-actionscript-and-alchemy/

Answer (score 0):

You can use AMF to pass an ActionScript ByteArray.  So you're set on the Actionscript side.  On the server side, there are slim pickings for AMF server implementations in C++.  I use BlazeDS for Java, but the only one I can seem to find for C++ is [AMFPP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/amfpp/).

Comment: Scott I think you misunderstood the question. It is about Adobe Alchemy, a framework to compile C and C++ code to Flash bytecode, so this is a client-side only question.